# What is an unconstrained conversion operator template and what is it good for?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

Consider this class snippet:

```
class A
{
public:
    template <class T>
    operator const T &() const;   
};
```

In what situations is such a templated conversion operator good for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not seen it converting to a reference (since you'll
typically want to return a temporary), but it's usually part of
a trick to overload on the return type.  You're main class will
have a number of different getters (or other functions which
return different types), and the generic getter will return
a Proxy with this type of conversion operator:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T typedGet() const { /*...*/ }

    class Proxy
    {
        Main const* myOwner;
    public:
        Proxy( Main const& owner ) : myOwner( owner ) {}
        template <typename T>
        operator T()() const { return myOwner->typedGet<T>(); }
    };
    Proxy get() const { return Proxy( *this ); }
};
```

With this, and an instance of `MyClass`, you can write:

```
int x = myObj.get();
std::string y = myObj.get();
```

This is often used for things like configuration file entries,
where `typedGet` will use `std::istringstream` to convert the
string in the configuration file to whatever type is desired
(and of of course, there will be a specialization for
std::string, since you don't want or need the
`std::istringstream`.)

With C++11, another possible solution would be:

```
auto x = myObj.get<int>();
auto y = myObj.get<std::string>();
```

I'm not totally convinced—this does look a bit like abuse
of `auto`, but I can see arguments for it.  And it certainly
simplifies the implementation of `MyClass`, since you can forgo
the proxy.

Comment: Thank you! The idea with overloading on return types was new to me.